# html/CSS code to minimize the extra spaces in the web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

My web page have multiple tabs and each tab has some content included through html file.
When user click on Tab1, i am displaying few boxes with image as shown in the below fiddle.
[Code Demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xs9C9eWKUYBI32hXqSWc?p=preview)

We can notice more space in the page before and after the boxes are displayed and there is a bar displayed with some heading, after the heading bar also lot of unused space can be seen. Please suggest how to remove those unwanted gaps before and after the boxes.I dont want to minimise the tab content displayed area.
I tried minimizing the height, though the problem remained the same.

HTML code:

```
<div class="tabs">
   <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
        <label for="tab-1">Tab1</label>

         <div class="content" style="width:700px;height:700px;">
           <!-- <embed type="text/html" src="summary.html"> -->
             <iframe src="tab1.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
        <label for="tab-2">Tab2</label>
        <div class="content">
           <iframe src="tab2.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
        <label for="tab-3">Tab3</label>
        <div class="content">
           <iframe src="tab3.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you guys using bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/  Bootstrap grid system is good for this kind of thing.

Comment: @nurdyguy - no, we are not using any frameworks.I need to achieve this using html,css, javascript. I want to reduce the extra spaces seen before and after the boxes with images are displayed and after the bar with heading. Please see the fiddle : https://plnkr.co/edit/Xs9C9eWKUYBI32hXqSWc?p=preview

Comment: @joann You set `<table width="100%" height="50%" class="padding">` so that table will hold 50% of the page's height, no matter what you put in it.  In this case you just put 1 row in it so the row is centered in that table.  Change the `height="50%"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly see if this is what you are looking for

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gAob4AkA66v4MCk7YnCn?p=preview)

> I just removed the inline height that you had given for the `<table>` element in the tab1.html file.
>   That was the reason you were getting extra spaces.